# Difference between pushstate and hasbangs?

Tags: ajax, html, pushstate, hashbang

I wanted to ask you guys, what is the better use for anchor links? Rather using hashbangs or using pushstate? I have read that hashbangs are out of time and pushstate would be better for SEO, but pushstate is only supported in new modern browseres...
So what would you recommend to change the url of my anchor links and why?

Best regards

Comment: "So what would you recommend to change the url of my anchor links" - It appears to me that you either mixed things up or you don't know what you want. The anchor is called "fragment" in URL terms and the part after the `#`. In the context of web pages it's _used as_ an anchor to focus (scroll to) named elements on a page. So if you have that requirement, you can't replace such URL with ones that do not have an anchor (well, technically you can using Javascript and other parts of the URL, but why bother).

Comment: Please clarify (edit your post and extend/rewrite it) whether or no you need the fragment in terms of "addressing" parts of the page whether it should just _represent the state_ of your application. Do you need the browser to scroll to parts of the page for you (very handy with documentations/references)? Will the content change when you fragments change?